# Catching an Exception with try-catch inside an if/switch block

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement, try-catch

I'm trying to catch a nullReferenceException within an if statement that is inside a switch statement... I've tried a number of different ways but I can't get the error to actually catch, it just keeps causing crashes.

```
               try 
                {
                switch (selectedOption)
                {

                    case "1":
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        if (textBox1.Text == "TEXT")
                        {
                            MessaageBox.Show("TEXT")
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("ELSETEXT")
                        }
                        throw new Exception;
                    case "3":
                        break;
                     default:
                        break;
                 }
               }
              catch (Exception)
                  {
                     MessageBox.Show("An error has occured");
                  }
```

I'm getting a null reference exception on case 2 at if textbox1 == text, when there is no value, I'd like to catch that null reference and display a message.

Thanks for any help/advice!

Comment: `throw new Exception;` is invalid syntax

Comment: I wouldn't use a `try..catch` to handle a `NullReferenceException`; it can easily be prevented. In your case an exception won't be thrown anyway, because `null == "TEXT"` evaluates to `false`, there is no exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put all the necessary code into a separate function and then check the value of the `strings`. Instead of using a `try{} catch{}`. Which is not advised if you are just checking for null values.

**Example Function:**

```cs
private void CheckText(string text, string equal,
    string error = "Text is empty", string notequal = "ELSETEXT") {
    // Message that we let the user see in the messageBox.
    string messageText = string.Empty;

    // Check if either of the string we want to check for is empty,
    // or null or consists only of whitespaces
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(equal)) {
        messageText = error;
    }
    // Check if both check string are equal
    else if (string.Equals(text, equal)) {
        messageText = equal;
    }
    else {
        messageText = notequal;
    }
    MessageBox.Show(messageText);
}
```

Now you can call that function in the `catch` block and give the necessary values as parameters into the function.

**Example FunctionCall:**

```cs
case "2":
    CheckText(textBox1.Text, "TEXT");
    break;
```

Comment: Perfect, that makes a lot more sense to check if the value is null before trying to use it thanks!